# Unable to edit the MS files having file name in different languages after migration in share point 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library

Recently, We have moved the SP 2013 applications from old server to new server. As the applications are being used world wide, some time document file names are a bit in different languages looks like special characters are there Although SP library has those files. Users were able to edit those files directly from client applications(MS word/Excel etc.). Now post migration ,users are unable to edit those files in new server.

But if we try to rename the file , then everything is working fine. Now the problem is we have huge no of files which are being used by different country users. So to rename files is not a solution.

So, Could anyone please suggest what could be the cause and resolution to that.

Thanks,
Kailash

Comment: How  you migrated the content, do you have same language packs on your source and target farms?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your clients have KB4489899 installed. If so, uninstall it and try to open those files again.